# <input> is hiding part of text which is visible in same <textarea> (Chromium)

Tags: html, css, chromium

I’m creating a sign language lexicon (for Swedish Sign Languale) centered around the transcription system usually used by researchers here in Sweden. The transcription is implemented as a Unicode font, which makes use of diacritics.

I have an HTML `input` element where the user types in a search query. Now, if the user starts by entering a diacritic mark, I'd like to be able to display that to the user, and if a diacritic it written without a preceding base character in front of it it will be placed a bit off to the left – and I'd thought I'd just add some `padding-left` to my text input element to make sure the first character would be visible even if it’s a diacritic... However, Chromium doesn't like that.

Below is an image of what it looks like in Chromium. To the left is a (yellow) `input` element, and to the right is (purple) `textarea` element (both containing the same string). The `textarea` shows the desired result, while the `input` element truncates the diacritics at the top and to the left.

[image: input and textarea elements side-by-side]

If one inspects the elements, one sees the following. (The text is truncated in the padding area of the `input` element, but not in the `textarea`.)

[image: same as above image, but in 'inspect element' mode]

I would prefer to use an `input` element if I can.

Is there any way I could style the `input` element so that it won't truncate my text in the padding region?

This problem does not appear in Firefox, where both the `textarea` an input elements look the same, with no truncating going on.

The following snippet also shows the problem (at least if you're running Chromium).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "FreeSans-SWL";
  src: url("https://zrajm.github.io/teckentranskription/freesans-swl.ttf");
}
input, textarea {
  font-family: "FreeSans-SWL";

  /* make textarea & input look the same */
  vertical-align: top;
  border: .25em inset #888;
  padding: .25em .5em;
}
```

```html
<input value="">                     
<textarea rows=1></textarea>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: I'd love to. But where can I put minimal reproducible example which uses a web font?

Comment: You might click on `<>` button and create a snippet here.

Comment: Regarding the Snippet that Kosh recommends, we have something of an introduction/tutorial over on [Meta]: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Awright. Added a snippet.